# Python open() append and read, file.read() returns empty string

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

Noticed an odd behavior when attempting to call `read()` on a file opened in `a+` mode (Python 3.4.1)

**As seen here**
[File mode for creating+reading+appending+binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757887/file-mode-for-creatingreadingappendingbinary)
It's possible to open a file in read/append mode *supposedly*.

**However**
This code:

```
with open("hgrc", "a+") as hgrc:
            contents=hgrc.read()
```

returns `contents={str}''`. Which is unexpected based upon the answer posted above. 
Now, the following code

```
with open("hgrc", "r+") as hgrc:
            contents=hgrc.read()
```

returns `contents={str}'contents of hgrc.....'`, which is expected, but doesn't give us the option to append to the file.

**According to the specs**
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

`Modes 'r+', 'w+' and 'a+' open the file for updating (reading and writing);`
`note that 'w+' truncates the file. Append 'b' to the mode to open the file` `in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text` `files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the 'b' has no` `effect.`

**Which means** 
When we open a file in `a+` mode, we should be able to call `read()` on it and get the contents of the file back, correct?
Thoughts? Opinions? Etc??

Comment: see if my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598929/reading-a-file-in-c-different-behavior-for-r-and-a-flags/31599072#31599072) helps. It's on the `C` thread, but it should apply just as well

Comment: It helps to actually remember to click the button (;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a+` opens the file at the end for appending. You need to call `.seek(0)` on it if you want to then read in its contents, but at that point you might as well just use `r+`, because that opens the file at the start.

Comment: .seek(0) works. I wanted to be able to open the file to append and conditionally append a line to that file if it does not already contain that line. Alternatively, I could go as simple as 'r' if I simply needed to read. Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is true only for Python 3. In Python 2 `a+` opens the file for appending, and rewinds the file pointer. Of course, a `.seek(0)` doesn't do any harm in Python 2, but it's not strictly needed.

Comment: @Peterino I did not know that, I don't use 2.x much. Good to know, thank you!

Comment: seek doesnt work for me. still return empty string. i almost made the table flipped

Answer (score 7):

This is a Python 2 vs. Python 3 issue.

`open()` with `a+` behaves differently in the two Python versions. (Note: You reveal you're using Python *3.4.1*, but you're quoting the documentation for Python *2*!)

(In fact, the behavior you're looking for (in "*Which means*") works as intended with Python 2. I think they changed the behavior, because "appending" means "file pointer at end of file" to many folks.)

---

### Let's test this with Python3 ...

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jul 28 2015, 18:20:59) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lic = open('LICENSE', 'a+')
>>> lic.read()
''
>>> # Hmmm, no content? EOF, obviously. Let's reset the file pointer ...
>>> lic.seek(0)
0
>>> lic.read()
'Apache License\nVersion 2.0, January 2004\n...'
```

### Same thing with Python2 ...

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lic = open('LICENSE', 'a+')
>>> lic.read()
'Apache License\nVersion 2.0, January 2004\n...'
>>> lic.seek(0)
>>> lic.read()
'Apache License\nVersion 2.0, January 2004\n...'
```

**Conclusion:** You're safe using the `seek(0)` *always* after opening a file with `a+`, regardless to which Python version you use. This seems to be specific to the `a+` mode.

---

### Why does a system call behave differently across two Python versions?

One would think file manipulation is a system call, hence it's handled by the operating system. This is different with Python, as it looks according to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> **Note:** Python doesn’t depend on the underlying operating system’s notion of text files; all the processing is done by Python itself, and is therefore platform-independent.

BTW, this behavior has been [reported as a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue22651) on the Python bug tracker.